# How to workaround this IE7 bug?

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-7

The code is here:
http://pastebin.me/6d3b7cfcd79b35615b41c2b8b305a159

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<meta http-equiv="Content-Style-Type" Content="text/css" />
<head>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>
<body>

<style type="text/css">
<!--
.problems-contents .wrapper-header{
    height:84px;
}
.lessons-wrapper {
    /*behavior:url(/MM/css/htc/ie-css3.htc);*/
    border:1px solid #CCCCCC;
    width:696px;
    height:450px;
}
#problems-all { display:none; }
div.active {
    -moz-border-radius:5px 5px 0 0;
    border-radius:5px 5px 0 0;
    -webkit-border-bottom-left-radius: 0px;
    -webkit-border-bottom-right-radius: 0px;
    -webkit-border-top-left-radius: 5px;
    -webkit-border-top-right-radius: 5px;
    background:none repeat scroll 0 0 white;
    border-color:#CCCCCC;
    border-style:solid solid none;
    border-width:1px 1px 0;
    cursor:default;
    float:right;
    height:26px;
    line-height:26px;
    text-align:center;
    width:120px;
    margin-left:10px;
    font-size: 11px;
    font-weight: normal;
    position:relative;
}
div.non-active {
    -moz-border-radius:5px 5px 0 0;
    border-radius:5px 5px 0 0;
    -webkit-border-bottom-left-radius: 0px;
    -webkit-border-bottom-right-radius: 0px;
    -webkit-border-top-left-radius: 5px;
    -webkit-border-top-right-radius: 5px;
    height:26px;
    line-height:26px;
    text-align:center;
    width:120px;
    float:right;
    cursor:hand;
    cursor:pointer;
    border-color:#DDD;
    border-style:solid solid none;
    border-width:1px 1px 0;
    margin-left:10px;
    font-size: 11px;
    font-weight: normal;
    position:relative;
}
.lessons-tab-header {
    float:right;
    font-size:12px;
    font-weight:bold;
    margin-top: 57px;
    position:absolute;
    /*z-index:10;*/
    display:inline-block;
    width:278px;
    left:418px;
}
.rightmargin10 { margin-right:10px; }

.problems-contents{
        position:absolute;
        top:92px;
        left:50px;
        height:452px;
        width:698px;
        background:white;
        display:none;
        z-index: 20;
         width: 698px;
    }

.cross{
    float:right;
    margin: 4px 4px 0 0;
    width:12px;
    zoom : 1;
    line-height:16px;
}

.cross a{    
    color: red;
    font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 16px;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-decoration: none;
    line-height:16px;
}
.wrapper-header {
    background-color:#E6E6E6;
    height:50px;
    padding-left:13px;
    font-size:20px;
    font-weight:bold;
}
-->
</style>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function show(){
        $(".problems-contents").show();                     
        $('#problems-incorrect').hide();
        $('#problems-all').show();
    }
</script>

<a href="javascript:show();">show</a>

<div class="problems-contents">
  <div class="lessons-wrapper" id="problems-all">
    <div class="wrapper-header">
      <div class="cross"><a href="javascript:$('.problems-contents').hide();void(0);">X</a></div>
      <div class="lessons-tab-header">
        <div class="non-active" onclick="$('#problems-all').hide();$('#problems-incorrect').show();">Missed Problems</div>
        <div class="active">All Problems</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="lessons-wrapper" id="problems-incorrect">
    <div class="wrapper-header">
      <div class="cross"><a href="javascript:$('.problems-contents').hide();void(0);">X</a></div>
      <div class="lessons-tab-header">
        <div class="active">Missed Problems</div>
        <div class="non-active" onclick="$('#problems-incorrect').hide();$('#problems-all').show()">All Problems</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</body>
```

Click "Show", click "Missed problems", Click the red "X" (top right), click "Show" again and the tabs are messed up.

It only happens in IE7. How to fix it?

Comment: I get the feeling that it has to do with IE7 not properly recognizing display: inline-block (https://www.google.ca/search?q=ie7+inline-block) Also, float: right + position:absolute + left:418px ?

Comment: ya I would say isotrope is right... you got display:inline-block and floats and absolute positions.  IE7 is probably getting confused with all those styles staking

Comment: Removing the floats does not help. One thing does help: removing the position:absolute from .problems-contents, but I want to keep that.

Comment: I found a solution by adding position: absolute; to .lessons-wrapper

Answer (score 0):

I do have a temporary solution till you not found any good solution. When you creating that tab by javascript, after creation try to refresh it. For example

```
$('#yourtabParent').html($('#yourtabParent').html());
```

It'll fix your problem but as you can see it's not a perfect solution :( 
If you not got any solution then I'll have a look at it at free time. Because it's a good question